# importing a 3d model in three.js

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

i tried importing my 3d model but its not loading its just at a black screen and i am getting an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'itemStart'). i have my code below, let me know if you need more specified detail about it.

```
 // Scene
 const scene = new THREE.Scene();
 scene.background = new THREE.Color("grey");

 // Base camera
 const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,)
 camera.position.set(0,100,800);

 // full screen webgl renderer
 const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 // make sure project is responsive based on window resizing
 window.addEventListener('resize', () =>{
     renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
     camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

     camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 })

//   add a light
  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555500,4)
  scene.add(light);

 // load object
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('do-yatte/yatte4.gltf', function (gltf) {
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
  })


const render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render)

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
```

To this:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
```

The THREE namespace is not needed.

Comment: i tried that but i get an error saying " GLTF Loader is not defined

Comment: Make sure you are importing the GLTFLoader at the top of your file, E.G. `import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/build/three.module.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';` If you are and it's still not working, then you'll have to provide a minimal working example on JSFiddle or CodePen to debug further.